# "No build task to run found" error on Visual Studio Code

Tags: build, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a build task to build my C program, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.26.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 installed. The `task.json` file is in a `.vscode` folder, and this folder is in the same directory as the `clock.c` file.

The `task.json` content is:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build clock app",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "clang -std=c11 -g -o clock -I. clock.c",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "echo": true,
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue running on Raspbian. 
I created a new tasks.json based on a template which VS Code seemed to have built in.

My tasks.json file looks like:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have .net Core SDK and Runtimes installed for .net core 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in the context of a Java/Spring Boot project so "*your mileage may vary*".

1. In VS Code with your project open, invoke your build (`Ctl`+`Sft`+`b`).
2. VS Code should show `No build task to run found. Configure Built Task...` Click on that text.

   - [image: VS Code]
3. Click on the resulting `Create task.json file from template` text (pictured below)

   - [image: VS Code]
4. You should now be presented options appropriate to your project/setup. Here is mine (below). Yours will likely be different. You'll need to make the appropriate selection for your project/setup and the `task.json` file will be configured for you.

   - [image: VS Code]
5. Save the `task.json` file.
6. You should now be able to successfully build (`Ctl`+`Sft`+`b`).